useNavigation changes URL but not does not render or display component
Consider the following code:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hardcore-lake-mptzw3
App.jsx:
import ContextProvider from "./provider/contextProvider";
import Routes from "./routes";
function App() {
  console.log("In App");

  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <Routes />
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

Routes.jsx:
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { provideContext } from "./provider/contextProvider";
import Component1 from "./pages/Component1";
import Component2 from "./pages/Component2";
const Routes = () => {
  const { token } = provideContext();

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/Component2",
      element: <Component2 />,
    },
    {
      path: "/Component1",
      element: <Component1 />,
    },
  ]);


  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default Routes;

pages/Component1.jsx:
const Component1 = () => {
  console.log("In Component1");

  return <div>Component1</div>;
};

export default Component1;

pages/Component2.jsx:
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { provideContext } from "../provider/contextProvider";

const Component2 = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setToken } = provideContext();
  console.log("In Component2");
  const onClick = () => {
    setToken("Token");
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate("/Component1");
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Component2;

provider/ContextProvider.jsx:
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const Context = createContext();

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState("Initial");

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ token, setToken }}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};

export const provideContext = () => {
  return useContext(Context);
};

export default ContextProvider;

When clicking the button in Component2, the URL changes but the UI still shows Component2.
Component 1 is not even rendered once.
Interestingly, if i remove the setTimeout() in Component2.jsx function OR remove const { token } = provideContext(); in Routes.jsx, the issue goes away. Not sure what is going.

No errors in the console. But when clicking the button in Component2, the path changes to /Component1 while still showing Component2 in the screen. It takes an extra button click before Component1 renders to the screen
I was just playing around hence why there is a setTimeout. It's never meant for any real implementation

Issue is declaring the router inside the ReactTree. The setToken("Token"); enqueues a state update in ContextProvider and triggers consumers like Routes to rerender, and when Routes renders it redeclares a new router which interrupts any current navigation actions being processed.
Either move declaring the router outside the ReactTree:
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { provideContext } from "./provider/ContextProvider";
import Component1 from "./pages/Component1";
import Component2 from "./pages/Component2";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/Component2",
    element: <Component2 />,
  },
  {
    path: "/Component1",
    element: <Component1 />,
  },
]);

const Routes = () => {
  const { token } = provideContext();

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default Routes;

Or memoize the router so it's not redeclared each render cycle when the context state updates:
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { provideContext } from "./provider/ContextProvider";
import Component1 from "./pages/Component1";
import Component2 from "./pages/Component2";

const Routes = () => {
  const { token } = provideContext();

  const router = useMemo(() =>
    createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path: "/Component2",
        element: <Component2 />,
      },
      {
        path: "/Component1",
        element: <Component1 />,
      },
    ]), [] // <-- add any required dependencies here
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default Routes;

You really shouldn't need to use a setTimeout to issue the navigation action. Remove setTimeout in Component2.
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { provideContext } from "../provider/ContextProvider";

const Component2 = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setToken } = provideContext();

  const onClick = () => {
    setToken("Token");
    navigate("/Component1");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Component2;

